# Override_settings not working at runtime with pytest DJANGO

Tags: django, pytest-django

In my settings.py file inside my django proyect I added a new constant `ALLOW_SELF_REGISTRATION`, that constant will allow or not a url in the proyect in the way:

```py
if settings.ALLOW_SELF_REGISTRATION:
     urlpatterns += [path(
                  "self_registration/", views.self_registration_client, name="self_registration"
                     ),]
```

My problem is that I need to test when that constant is set to `False` in that case the url should not be added and a test to that url must raise a `NoReverseMatch`.

I found that the override_settings is not working as expected, I do differents attemps to see if any could work, but no.

Until now i tried:

```py
def test_constant_on_change_edit_urls_on_false(client):
    with override_settings(ALLOW_SELF_REGISTRATION=False):
        with pytest.raises(NoReverseMatch):
            response = client.get(reverse('profiles:self_registration'))
```

If I print the value of the constant in that test is set to `True` (as default) and not `False` as it should by the `override_settings` context manager.

I need a way to override that constant at runtime inside the tests so I can test that functionality. Also tried:

```py
@override_settings(ALLOW_SELF_REGISTRATION=False)
def test_constant_on_change_edit_urls_on_false(client):
    with pytest.raises(NoReverseMatch):
        response = client.get(reverse('profiles:self_registration'))
```

But also failed.

There is any way to change that value at runtime during the tests?

Comment: That is the correct way to modify settings in a test. Are there other places where `ALLOW_SELF_REGISTRATION` is being used or being set?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the exact same problem yesterday!

You can solve it by monkeypatching the settings object. When applied to your situation, you'll get something like this:

```py
import sys
from importlib import reload as reload_module

import pytest
from django.urls import NoReverseMatch, clear_url_caches, reverse

def reload_modules(*modules):
    for module in modules:
        reload_module(sys.modules[module])


def test_constant_on_change_edit_urls_on_false(client, monkeypatch, settings):
    # monkeypatch settings property:
    monkeypatch.setattr("your_project.urls.settings.ALLOW_SELF_REGISTRATION", False)
    # reload url configs
    reload_modules("your_project.urls", settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
    # clear the aggressively cached urls
    clear_url_caches()

    # continue with the test:
    with pytest.raises(NoReverseMatch):
        response = client.get(reverse('profiles:self_registration'))
```